# simple query: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

First crack at using SQLite+Java and I'm recieving an error when I attempt to execute a simple simple query.

Error:
    not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver

Query:

```
String sql = 
    "select Asset, Qty*Price+Fees as Cost \n" +
    "from   Transactions t \n" +
    "       inner join TransactionItems i on t.Id = i.TransactionId \n" +
    "where  TransDate <= ? \n";

try (PreparedStatement stmt = cnn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    java.sql.Date dte = new java.sql.Date(SumDate().getTimeInMillis());
    stmt.setDate(1, dte);

    try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
        while(rs.next()) {
            PortfolioSummaryItem item = new PortfolioSummaryItem(PortfolioSummary.this);
            item.Load(rs);
            items.put(item.asset,item);
        }
        rs.close();
    }

    stmt.close();
```

Comment: What are those "`\n`" for?

Comment: Please post the full error message with call trace (if available).

Comment: The "\n"s are for debugging mostly (cut and paste the query to an editor).

Comment: What about `catch` parts for your `try`s? Do you have them?

Comment: Its a bit of a throw away app, so I'm not bothering with catching errors

Comment: Your SQL seems to be fine. Have you picked up the right driver for the  SQLite version you are using?

Comment: Please post the exact SQLite version you use, as well as driver class and connection string .

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This was a simple cut/paste style error. When using prepared statements, you shouldn't then pass the SQL into the `executeQuery`.

Change:

```
try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){
```

To:

```
try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()){
```

This was overriding the `preparedStatement`.

What it was complaining about was executing a query with a '?' in it since it wasn't the prepared query.

Comment: I feel like this problem should have one of those trackers you see in code that says: increment this counter everytime you search for this error and find this comment (I'm at least at 5 now)

Answer (score 0):

Check the jdbc driver you have in the libs folder.
It looks like it has not implemented the methods you have called.

Try downloading the driver from here:
https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads

Comment: 1-Can you double check; is there any other jars in the path? 2- Can you please add the line where you set the driver?

Comment: 1-When I unlink the lib in my IDE I get: `No suitable driver found`. 2. What do you mean by "set the driver"?

Comment: Try this to check the driver:   DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData(); System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName()); System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());

Comment: Driver name: SQLiteJDBC
Driver version: native